# Append text to end of text box dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have the following input tag:

```
<input type="text" id="title" class="title" maxlength="20>
```

I need " day" to be appended to the end of the text in the box as the user types. How is this done with jQuery?

I've tried this:

```
$('#title').on('keyup', function() {
this.value = this.value+' day';
});
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean "as the user types"? What if they enter "a" and you append "day" to get "aday", and then they move the cursor to the end and type "b"? Do you then append "day" again to get "adaybday"? Wouldn't it be nicer to wait until the user leaves that field and then test whether the value already ends in "day" (and if not add it then)? Try the `blur` event rather than `keyup`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery to append the text at the end, and then move the caret to the desired position:

```
$('#title').on('keyup', function(e) {
    // Ignore if backspace is pressed
    if(e.keyCode == 46){
       return false;
    }

    // Set the value based on the current value length
    // If it's longer than 3, "day" is already appended
    this.value = (this.value.length<3)?this.value+="day":this.value;

    // Move caret to the latest added character
    var caretPos = this.value.length-3;
     if(this.createTextRange) {
        var range = this.createTextRange();
        range.move('character', caretPos);
        range.select();
    }
    else {
        if(this.selectionStart) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
        }
        else
            this.focus();
    }
});
```

[Live, working jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sWQ4D/4/)

Comment: @user1689607: I misunderstood the question. I'm fixing it.

Comment: It's almost impossible to do a select all and delete, though.

Comment: @Jaxkr: no problem. I couldn't fix the select all (CTRL+A) issue though.