# Append input with defined text in textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is to append `.com` in textfield during user input. Textfield will be empty and `.com` will be shown during typing domain name. Here is my not working code:

HTML

```
Enter domain name: <input type="text" id="domain">
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keypress(function(){
    $("#domain").val(this.value + ".com");
  });
});
```

Not working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/UUzux/25/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: better solution to add `.com` in other control or at least on blur with checking existing `.com` in the end

Comment: I think it would be clearer UX design to have a `.com` label after the text box to indicate that `.com` is included.

Comment: What happens if the user wants to specify a `.org`, `.tv`, `.co.uk` (and so on...) TLD instead?

Comment: This might be helpful if you are using jQuery:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242967/append-text-to-end-of-text-box-dynamically-with-jquery

Comment: I only allowed 1 domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought this was a great question.  For a sleek solution, you could use the following code taken from

**[Set keyboard caret position in html textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox)**

to manually set the caret position in the input field:

```
function setCaretPosition(elemId, caretPos) {
    var el = document.getElementById(elemId);

    el.value = el.value;

    if (el !== null) {

        if (el.createTextRange) {
            var range = el.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', caretPos);
            range.select();
            return true;
        } else {
            if (el.selectionStart || el.selectionStart === 0) {
                el.focus();
                el.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
                return true;
            } else { // fail
                el.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you'd implement it as follows:

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
    var val = $("#domain").val();

    val = val.replace(/\..*/g, ''); // replace this with whatever regex you need to deny whatever input you want.
    $("#domain").val(val + ".com");

    var caretPos = val.length;
    var elemId = "domain";

    setCaretPosition(elemId, caretPos);
});
```

Which will take anything after any `.` character out of the string, replace it each time with '.com' (you can replace this regex to handle whatever you need), and then set the cursor position to right before the '.com'

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/UUzux/40/)

Also, to enable editing in the middle of the string you'd have to get the caret position.  There's a stackoverflow question here

**[Get cursor position (in characters) within a text Input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field)**

With good examples.  I modified one of the answers as follows:

```
getCaretPosition = function (elemId) {
    var input = $('#' + elemId);
    if (!input) return; // No (input) element found
    if ('selectionStart' in input[0]) {
        // Standard-compliant browsers
        return input[0].selectionStart;
    } else if (document.selection) {
        // IE
        input.focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        var selLen = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
        sel.moveStart('character', -input.value.length);
        return sel.text.length - selLen;
    }
}
```

And then your jQuery would look like this:

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
    var val = $("#domain").val();
    var elemId = "domain";

    var caretPos = getCaretPosition(elemId);

    val = val.replace(/\..*/g, '');
    $("#domain").val(val + (val ? ".com" : ""));

    setCaretPosition(elemId, caretPos);
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/UUzux/42/) with that implementation.

Comment: I never thought it's gonna be this complex. Thank you very much for your time to code and explain to me. Regex is giving me problem because the .com keeps adding itself every time I type so I suppress special char with the keyboard input instead. Here's the updated js: http://jsfiddle.net/UUzux/43/ 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this would help you.
http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/UUzux/35/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var prevText;
  $("input").keyup(function(e){
      var str=$("input").val().replace(".com", "");

 str=str+'.com'

      $("#domain").val( str );

  });
});
```

well here is the updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/UUzux/39/

But still looks aweful without caret moved

Comment: without movind caret it looks awful

Comment: Also doesn't allow you to correct errors with backspace.

Comment: I will try to implement it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").keyup(function (e) {
        var kcode;
        if (!e){
            var e = window.event;
        }

        if (e.keyCode){
            kcode = e.keyCode;
        }
        else if (e.which){ 
            kcode = e.which;
        }

        if (kcode == 8 || kcode == 46){
            return false;
        }

        this.value = this.value.replace('.com', '');

        $("#domain").val(this.value + ".com");

        var curpos = this.createTextRange();
        curpos.collapse(true);
        curpos.moveEnd('character', this.value.length - 4);
        curpos.select();
    });
});
```

I had to borrow some code from [Joel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664631/disable-backspace-and-delete-key-with-javascript-in-ie) on this post regarding disabling the backspace and delete keys. Just as he states in his post be careful using `e.keyCode` because not all browsers use it, some use `e.Which`.

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UUzux/41/)

Update: [link](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) to full list of key codes.

Comment: I use bowheart solution but thanks for the key codes list. Help me with integrating with his solution. Thank you